# Is there a way to cd $CI_PROJECT_NAME and use git diff together to store files in a variable?

Tags: shell, makefile, gitlab-ci

I am trying to get a list of .bpmn files that have changed using git diff and replace their versionTag with GITLAB_TAG but the script in makefile gives me an error No such file or directory.

```
update-camunda-version:
 BPMN_FILES := $(shell cd "$(CI_PROJECT_NAME)" && git diff --name-only @~..@ | grep '\.bpmn')
 cd $(CI_PROJECT_NAME) &&  sed -i 's/camunda:versionTag=".*"/camunda:versionTag="$(GITLAB_TAG)"/g' $(BPMN_FILES)
```

Even when I do this without `cd CI_PROJECT_NAME` it gives me the same error.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a make rule? The recipes of make rules are shell scripts. `BPMN_FILES := ...` is not a syntactically correct shell script. Moreover, using the `shell` make macro in a recipe (which is already a shell script) is **always** wrong. You should rework your recipe to turn it into real shell scripts. Beware: all lines are executed by a different script and the recipe is expanded by make before it is passed to the shell. Note that `git -C <directory> ...` avoids having to `cd`.

Comment: Sorry, _...are executed by a different script..._ should be _...are executed by a different shell..._. This means that you cannot assign a shell variable in a line and use it in another. Unless you joint the lines with shell operators (`;`, `&&`, `|`, `||`...) and use the line continuation (backslash at the end of the lines).